# Identifier has already been declared react native

Tags: react-native

So I have created a simple react-native following the Coursera lectures.

My Menu component just holds a list of recipes and displays them on the device.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

function Menu(props){

    const renderMenuItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return(
            <ListItem
                key={index}
                title={item.name}
                subtitle={item.description}
                hideChevron={true}
                onPress={() => props.onPress(item.id)}
                leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/uthappizza.png')}}
            />
        );
    }

    return(
        <FlatList 
            data={props.dishes}
            renderItem={renderMenuItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
    )
}

export default Menu;
```

Next, there is the DishdetailComponent which renders the details of each dish.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';

function RenderDish(props) {

    const dish = props.dish;

        if (dish != null) {
            return(
                <Card
                featuredTitle={dish.name}
                image={require('./images/uthappizza.png')}>
                    <Text style={{margin: 10}}>
                        {dish.description}
                    </Text>
                </Card>
            );
        }
        else {
            return(<View></View>);
        }
}

function Dishdetail(props) {
    return(<RenderDish dish={props.dish} />);
}

export default Dishdetail;
```

And finally, I have the MainComponent which is like the top component holding the two previous components.

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent';

class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dishes: DISHES,
            selectedDish: null
        };
    }

    onDishSelect(dishId) {
        this.setState({selectedDish: dishId})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onPress={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />
                <Dishdetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]} />
            </View>
        );
    }

}

export default Main;
```

When I run the app I get this

[image: Error]

Did I miss something? Here is my [repo](https://github.com/theo82/Multiplatform-Mobile-App-Development-with-React-Native) if you want to have a closer look.

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: @Ahmed Rebai. The error is displayed in the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few moments here:

1) Seems you forgot to import the `Menu` component at the top of imports

2) You simply have a typo in the import of `DishdetailComponent`

Just paste these lines instead of yours

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import { DISHES } from "../shared/dishes";
import Dishdetail from "./DishDetailComponent";
import Menu from "./MenuComponent";
```

Also, sometimes bunder crashes and don't reload.
To fix this I would suggest using 
`yarn start --reset-cache` command (but don't forget to kill previous Metro Bundler instance) :)